# Where to change this colour setting in KDevelop?

Tags: 11.10, kde, colors

In KDevelop, when you change the name of a variable, a function or the definition of a function, a little message appears below the editor (see image). In this instance it says "Declare function 'get' as: *1* public cv::Matx34f". However, I can't read this because the background is ?brown? and the text is black.

This changed after upgrading to Kubuntu 11.10. Before that it used to be a light blue background.

How do I get that old background back? I tried under Setting>Editor>Fonts&Colors but there are thousands of options. I also tried under system settings>appearance. No luck either.

[image: The offending colour scheme.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found it. A friend told me, it's called a "tooltip" and can be changed under
`System Settings > Application Appearance > Colors > Colors > Tooltip Background`. This of course is troublesome, as the `Tooltip Text` is white by default.

So, I put it back to how it was in 11.04: Black text on light blue. The light blue has the value `#BEDFF`.

Comment: you should mark your answer as the answer you will get the reputation and it will help others find the answer. By the way good question

Comment: You probably aren't aware, that marking one's own answer as accepted is only possible after a wait of two days.

Comment: Sorry its been a while :)

Comment: Hi, I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I cannot find `System Settings > Application Appearance > Colors > Colors > Tooltip Background`. In fact I cannot find `System Settings > Application Appearance`. where is it?

Comment: Are you using KDE?

Comment: `$ sudo find / -iname kde
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-browsers.d/kde
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/kde
/usr/lib/kde4/imports/org/kde
/usr/lib/kde4/platformimports/touch/org/kde ...` Am I using kde? How to know? What I can do is changing the colors but only for the text-editor, and not the whole interface of kdevelop