# How to get dark color chema for kdevelop?

Tags: 14.04, themes, kdevelop

I am trying to change my colr schema of my kdevelop to solarized-dark, but I arrive to change only the colors in the text editor and not the whole interface.

I have also searched for solution like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/74047/357763), but I am not finding `Application Appearance`; or others like using:changing Gnome colors, but this is changing anything, not only kdevelop. I have downloaded the schema [here](https://www.kdevelop.org/screenshots/dark-color-scheme), but it is still applied only the text-editor.

How to do it? Is it possible?

---

By the way,

```
$ kdevelop -v
```

is returning

```
Qt: 4.8.6
KDE Development Platform: 4.13.3
KDevelop: 4.6.0
```

How is that possible, because i see on the site that only 4.7.0 is released... Is it the version that I use? How to pass in the 4.7.0 version and updating only with released versions?

---

I am adding a photo of my problem:

[image]

I do not like the light border of my KDevelop. Is there a way to fix that and make it have the same color schema as the editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install Kubuntu to do so. I am sure that a special customization of the colors in the Ubuntu may lead to something similar (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454372/dark-gtk-theme-for-ubuntu-14-04) for some ideas), but did not try.