# KDevelop color themes with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, themes, kdevelop

I would like to change the (color) theme in KDevelop to a [dark theme](https://www.kdevelop.org/sites/www.kdevelop.org/files/2016-08/kdevelop-darktheme.png) as advertised on the [KDevelop website](https://www.kdevelop.org/). This setting is places in `settings -> color theme` where a list of color themes should be available. With Ubuntu 20.04 there is just a single option bringing the application back to the default color theme.

Is there a possibility to change the theme of KDevelop in Ubuntu 20.04?

There is a related [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576149/how-to-get-dark-color-chema-for-kdevelop), but it is targeting Ubuntu 14.04 which did not use GNOME. Furthermore there is no accepted answer.

I am aware that the colors of the editor can be changed, but I want to change the color theme of the whole application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

KDevelop reads colour schemes from `~/.local/share/color-schemes/` and `/usr/share/color-schemes/`.

Ubuntu's `kde-style-breeze` package includes the standard KDE ones (among other things), or you can find many here: https://store.kde.org/browse/cat/112/ord/top/

[Originally I suggested the `breeze` package - `kde-style-breeze` pulls in less unrelated content as pointed out by @xCovelus]

Answer (score 1):

Following [FLHerne's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1311760/601939)*, I searched in apt, and fixed the general window style through:

```
sudo apt install kde-style-breeze
```

After that, **KDevelop -> Settings -> Color Theme**, and many new themes appeared, such as **Breeze Dark**.
For the source code area:
**Settings -> Configure -> Editor -> Fonts & Colors / Schema** -> (select some of these, as **Breeze Dark**)

* upvote that answer as well, please